# How did Baasha make war against Asa a decade after his death?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, chronology

Ba'asha became king of Israel in Asa's 3rd year, reigned 24 years and died in his 26th year(1 Ki 15:38). This is apparently contradicted by 2 Chronicles 15:19 - 16:1

> There was no more war until the thirty-fifth year of Asa’s reign. In the thirty-sixth year of Asa’s reign Baasha king of Israel went up against Judah and fortified Ramah to prevent anyone from leaving or entering the territory of Asa king of Judah.

There are two explanations I've seen to explain the timing of Baasha's post-mortem war:

- The word translated 'reign' may also be translated 'kingdom,' so perhaps the 36 years are being counted from the kingdom's division, placing this attack in Asa's 17th year. Other events in this chapter, however, are undeniably being dated from the start of Asa's personal reign(reform in his 15th year), so this explanation doesn't really hold water.
- 35th/36th is an error for some lower number, like 25th/26th. I don't read/speak Hebrew but I don't see any lower number that resembles the Hebrew for 35 & 36. Additionally, it would require a scribe to have messed up in both 15:19 and 16:1.

Are there any alternative explanations for this apparent contradiction or ways to get around the problems I have with the main theories?

Answer (score 1):

Divrei Soferim on DHY II 16:1 says it was counting from the beginning of the division to signify that this was the point that there was a chance of the two kingdoms becoming fully one again. That it otherwise would use the normal way of dating doesn't really bother me, the change was just to bring across that point.
Aside form that, I dont really know any meforshim on Divrei Hayamim, hope this heps